Convert JSON array of key/value pairs into values with a comma seperator using jq
I have the following JSON.
{"foo": [
      {
        "bar": "baz"
      },
      {
        "bar": "baz"
      },
      {
        "bar": "baz"
      }
    ]
}

I'd like to convert this using jq into the following
"baz", "baz", "baz"

How do I do this using jq without any flags?
.foo.[].bar using https://jqplay.org/ gets you to having them on separate lines with no comma between them, but I need them to have commas in between and be on the same line.
"baz"
"baz"
"baz"


Re "How do I do this using jq without any flags?": Without any flags, you get valid JSON, and the actual formatting is irrelevant. Your desired output "baz", "baz", "baz" is not valid JSON, and would have to be constructed manually (e.g. with jq -r '.foo | map(.bar | @json) | join(",")'). But manual formatting requires a "raw output", which needs to be enabled with the --raw-output (or -r) flag.

imho in 2024 to use tools like jq for the things like this is a total overkill. This is a one-liner: const result = .foo.map(x => Object.values(x)).join(", ");

Extract all raw bar as array and pipe to @csv:
jq -r '[.foo.[].bar] | @csv'


echo '{"foo": [
      {
        "bar": "baz"
      },
      {
        "bar": "baz"
      },
      {
        "bar": "baz"
      }
    ]
}' | jq -r '[.foo.[].bar] | @csv'

Output:
"baz","baz","baz"

